# Azure SQL Advance Data Security (ADS) and Security Center Pricing

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have bit confusion on Azure SQL Security pricing as below, please help in this.

Security Center has cost $15/Server/Month. While enabling advanced data security for the SQL, it says 'Turn on Advanced Data Security for all databases on this server, at the cost of 15 USD/server/month. This includes Data Discovery & Classification, Vulnerability Assessment, and Advanced Threat Protection for the server.'

Both are pointing to the same cost or do we have to pay $15+$15=$30 altogether for a SQL server?

Thanks
Regards
Sakaldeep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-advanced-data-security). We need to pay only once.

*"The cost of ADS is aligned with Azure Security Center standard tier pricing per node, where a node is the entire SQL Database server or managed instance. You are thus paying only once for protecting all databases on the database server or managed instance with ADS."*

Comment: Hi Sakaldeep Yadav, you can accept it as the answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.